# Min Max Tour for VRP in OptaPlanner

Tags: java, optaplanner, traveling-salesman

I am new to OptaPlanner and trying to modify the existing VRP example to my needs.

My Problem: I want the uncapacitated VRP, like in the example tutorial/test/tutorial-01-uncapacitated.vrp. With the actual implementation, the optimizer mostly uses just one vehicle, because it only considers to minimize the total dstance.
I want to change the soft constraint, such that the Maximum Tour gets minimized. My objective is to get an equal utilization of the vehicles.

Below is the implemented drools soft constraints:

```
//###########################################################################
// Soft constraints
// ############################################################################
rule "distanceToPreviousStandstill"
when
    $customer : Customer(previousStandstill != null,$distanceFromPreviousStandstill : distanceFromPreviousStandstill)
then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $distanceFromPreviousStandstill);
end

rule "distanceFromLastCustomerToDepot"
when
    $customer : Customer(previousStandstill != null)
    not Customer(previousStandstill == $customer)
then
    Vehicle vehicle = $customer.getVehicle();
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $customer.getDistanceTo(vehicle));
end
```

I am trying to calculate the distances for each vehicle, and return a softconstraint for the vehicle with the highest distance.

Answer (score 1):

After minimizing the maximum tour, you'll also want it to minimize the 2nd maximum tour, and so forth.

See "fairness" and "load balancing" in the documentation. And the tennis example.